# Cross domain pdf loading

Tags: apache, cross-domain, subdomain

I have a website with something like this:
I have a folder with generated pdfs at http://www.example.com/mypdfs/mypdf.pdf;  but then I need to load pdfs from there using javascript from http://subdomain.example.com which is subdomain in the same folder, but of course I am getting a crossdomain error, how can I solve this? how can I tell apache to allow cross domain access to this subdomain?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify your .htaccess file to allow cross domain origin, you need to add :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

[Enabling CORS in apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

Comment: Inside of the pdfs folder? or in the root of the website?

Comment: in the root folder of your website

Comment: Well I am guessing that allow crossdomain to the whole application, I placed the .htaccess in the pdfs folder, I just needed it for the pdfs folder and it worked thanks a lot.