# Set HTTP Get Headers Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, get, cors

I am retrieving an image file from a different server than where the GET is being sent from, I am getting two fils one is located on the other server at `/var/www/html/test/image1.png` and the other file is at`/var/www/html/test/inside/image2.png` I am getting the files like this. I know the url http://xxx.xxx.xx/test/image1.png and http://xxx.xxx.xx/test/inside/image2.png and then I do this

```
function convertToDataURLviaCanvasBOTH(url, callback, outputFormat){
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null; 
};
img.src = url;
}

url1 = http://xxx.xxx.xx/test/image1.png;
url2 = http://xxx.xxx.xx/test/inside/image2.png

data1 = convertToDataURLviaCanvasBOTH(url1);
data2 = convertToDataURLviaCanvasBOTH(url2);
```

`data1` works great and I get it back, but then when it tires it for `url2` it fails and I get error

```
Image from origin 'http://xxx.xx.xx.x' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://sending-server.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Why does it work for the first and not the second when the 2nd is just in a sub folder of the 1st?

At the root file directory I also have

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sending-server.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

In a .htaccess file, which should always send the headers

Here are the request headers for url1

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.67.64.41
If-Range:"1083f-52648757feb05"
Origin:http://sending-server.com
Range:bytes=2596-2596
Referer:http://sending-server.com/info.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
```

And the request headers from url2

```
Provisional headers are shown //THERE IS A WARING SYMBOL ON THIS LINE
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Origin:http://sending-server.com
Referer:http://sending-server.com/info.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id:A760326C-C02F-41C6-A4F6-4B46AA7BC1C3
```

Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX I am the owner of both, see above for what I added

Comment: @JaromandaX I though putting .htaccess in the first directory does it also for all sub directories? how can I make sure?

Comment: You have to allow cross origin in /test/inside/ folder
to do that you have to modify your configuration file in that folder

Comment: @JayMar okay, doesn't a higher directory also allow it in lower directories? Do you mean modify my httpd.conf when you say configuration file?

Comment: if you're using apache then check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109354/cross-domain-pdf-loading/34109451#34109451

Comment: @JayMar I have done that with `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://sending-server.com"` but I am always coming for one place so I replaced the wildcard * with the auctally domain

Comment: btw, why not using relative paths ?

Comment: @JayMar they are different servers, I am sending GET to a different server

Comment: and both are yours ?

Comment: @JayMar yes they are both mine

Comment: @spenf10 Can you post the request headers to recommend the way to do correctly

Comment: @Vineet1982 added the request headers

Comment: @spenf10 change answer kindly let me know working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the exact setting of your .htaccess but the correct setting of .htaccess are:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
     ........
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

When performing certain types of cross-domain AJAX requests, modern browsers that support CORS will insert an extra "preflight" request to determine whether they have permission to perform the action.

```
OPTIONS /
Host: bar.com
Origin: http://foo.com
```

If bar.com is willing to accept the action, it may respond with the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE
```

Let me know the if it doesn't work

Comment: that didn't work, and my .htaccess only contains exactly what you have posted above and the two line I posted in my question that yours does not have, and doesn't the file match mean that it will only accept from a .php file? I am sending it from Javascript?

Comment: @spenf10 Change you Allow-Methods add options as it is the important one then try again let me know

Comment: that also didn't work, I have those in the .htaccess i had above, I have also tried just getting url2, and I got the error, what else could cause the problem with the sub directory?

Comment: your second request doesn't have the header origin add the header in the request then it will work. Origin: http://sending-server.com

Comment: right but how can I add that header? where does Origin:sending-server.com go?

Comment: post your javascript source to tell you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97172/discussion-between-spenf10-and-vineet1982).